# Recent update has me stuck in a log in loop

Tags: unity

So I tried rebooting my pc recently and now it won't let me log in. It just kicks me back to log in screen

I've tried `rm./home/*/.xauthorith`
Cannot remove is a directory

And a few of the other more common ones like purging nvidia. Just said the was no nvidia to purge

Comment: DON'T type `rm` commands if you don't know what they do!!!! Check my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terminal, type (use the correct username):

```
cd /home/your_username
ls -l .ICEauthority # (that's a lower case L)
ls -l .Xauthority   # (that's a lower case L)
```

If either `ls` command returns one of these (where it shows root, instead of your username):

```
-rw------- 1 root root 242476 Nov  6 12:48 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 root root 58     Nov  6 12:48 .Xauthority
```

Then type (changing your_username to the correct username):

```
sudo chown your_username:your_username .ICEauthority
```

and/or

```
sudo chown your_username:your_username .Xauthority
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing ownership didn't help me, but rolling back nvidia-304 helped. I've described it here: [stuck in login ubuntu 14.04 after trying everything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846862/stuck-in-login-ubuntu-14-04-after-trying-everything/847034#847034)