# stuck in login ubuntu 14.04 after trying everything

Tags: 14.04, login

I can't get past the login screen via GUI. After I enter the password, it takes me back to the same screen in 2 seconds. I don't see my usual background/wallpaper, just the stock purple screen. Things I've tried:

- I CAN log in via command line (ALT+CTL+F3)
- Tried replacing .Xauthority file and running chown on it
- /tmp has correct properties (drwxrwxrwt)
- checked .xsession-errors file, nothing obvious there (though it's possible I missed something)
- tried purging sources.list file
- reinstalled lightdm multiple times
- installed Ubuntu-desktop several times
- reinstalled Unity and ubuntu-gnome-desktop
- I AM able to create additional users but I am NOT able to get past the login screen regardless of who the user is.

I'm out of ideas, short of doing a clean install of Ubuntu. Please help?

EDIT: this is not a new system install question. I've been using Ubuntu for over a year without problems. I did a normal set of apt-get update upgrade and dist-upgrade over the weekend and now I can't login for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @KevinBowen that question seems to be dealing with boot/grub issues. My system IS booting. I just can't past the login screen. My questions might be a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/551991/ubuntu-stuck-login-screen) but I've tried all the solutions mentioned there without success.

Comment: Disk full? incorrect ownership or permission on your `$HOME` dir?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 1):

It's a temporary answer:

The problem I was experiencing is after recent upgrade, instantly past login I was logged in and then redirected back to login screen.

I've used this: [Is there any way to roll back the most recent upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34888/is-there-any-way-to-roll-back-the-most-recent-upgrade)
to roll back most recent upgrade. I've rolled back unity, it didn't help, then I rolled back nvidia-304 and it helped.

Edit:
After update I was struck again with the same problem and found a simpler solution here in comments http://www.linuxslaves.com/2016/05/3-ways-fix-ubuntu-gets-stuck-login-loop.html

I will past the relevant part of the comment by Foxjt:

The general consensus seemed to rotate around problems with the video drivers, so:

**sudo ubuntu-drivers devices**

This shows the required drivers for my Video card (nVidia G96 GeForce 9400 GT) as nvidia-340.

I ran:

**sudo apt-get install nvidia-340**

The messages showed that nvidia-304 was being removed and replaced with nvidia-340.

After a reboot, I was able to finally login!!! Hooray!!!

Comment: Update, stuck with it another time, found a simpler solution here: in comments: http://www.linuxslaves.com/2016/05/3-ways-fix-ubuntu-gets-stuck-login-loop.html    I will copy paste the comment: ... video drivers, so:

***sudo ubuntu-drivers devices***

This shows the required drivers for my Video card (nVidia G96 GeForce 9400 GT) as nvidia-340.

I ran:

***sudo apt-get install nvidia-340***

The messages showed that nvidia-304 was being removed and replaced with nvidia-340.

After a reboot, I was able to finally login!!! Hooray!!!